# Choosing M of N packets so sum is minimal multiple of K

Tags: algorithm

I saw this program on Codechef. 
There are N packets each containing some candies. (Eg: 1st contains 10, 2nd contains 4 and so on)
We have to select exactly M packets from it ( M<=N) such that total candies are divisible by K.
If there are more than one solution then output the one having lowest number of candies.

I thought its similar to Subset Sum problem but that is NP hard. So it will take exponential time.

I don't want the complete solution of this program. An algorithm would be appreciated. Thinking on it from 2 days but unable to get the correct logic.

1 ≤ M ≤ N ≤ 50000, 1 ≤ K ≤ 20
Number of Candies in each packet [1,10^9]

Comment: 1 ≤ M ≤ N ≤ 50000, 1 ≤ K ≤ 20

Comment: @AndroidDecoded Question title is bad, please fix it.  Eg, "Choosing M of N packets so sum is minimal multiple of K"

Comment: Done.. Thanks.. Yeah the title was bad..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `packets` contain the original packets.

Partition `k` into sums of `p = 1, 2, ..., m` numbers `>= 1` and `< k` (there are `O(2^k)` such partitions). For each partition, iterate over `packets` and add those numbers whose remainder modulo `k` is one of the partition's elements, then remove that element from the partition. Keep the minimum sum as well, and update a global minimum. Note that if `m > p`, you must also have `m - p` zeroes.

You might be thinking this is `O(2^k * n)` and it's too slow, but you don't actually have to iterate the `packets` array for each partition if you keep `num[i] = how many numbers have packets[i] % k == i`, in which case it becomes `O(2^k + n)`. To handle the minimum sum requirement too, you can keep `num[i] = the list of the numbers that have packets[i] % k == i`, which will allow you to always pick the smallest numbers for a valid partition.

Comment: Didn't understood the first line. What do you mean by partition k? How can I partition k?

Comment: As shown at [OEIS link](http://oeis.org/A000041) from wikipedia link, the number of partitions grows much more slowly than 2^K.  Eg, numbpart(20) is 627.  The method might be practical for K several times as large.  Eg, pari/gp statement `for(i=1,9,print(numbpart(i*10)))` shows that at `x=10, 20, 30, ... 90`, numbpart(x) is 42, 627, 5604, 37338, 204226, 966467, 4087968, 15796476, 56634173.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look again at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#Pseudo-polynomial_time_dynamic_programming_solution and note that K is relatively small. Furthermore, although N can be large, all you care about in the sums that involve N is the answer mod K. So there is a dynamic programming solution lurking around here, where at each step you have K possible values mod K, and you keep track of which of these values are currently attainable.

Comment: After looking at M, I think the state space is bigger but the problem is still doable: Step for i = 1 to N and at each step keep track of which combinations of (result mod K, using exactly m packets) are reachable using packets numbered 1..i. Work out the reachable combinations for i using the reachable combinations for i-1.